# Mysql - Select WHERE AND - VARIABLE does not work

Tags: php, mysql, variables, select, where-clause

I have the following problem:

```
//$sql = "SELECT name, number, letter FROM queues WHERE number='100' AND letter='S'";
      
$sql = "SELECT name, number, letter FROM queues WHERE number='".$contentnumber."' AND  
      letter='".$contentletter."'";
```

See both queries above.

Both give the following out when I execute: `var_dump($sql);`

```
string(121) "SELECT name, number, letter FROM queues WHERE number='100' AND letter='S'"
```

Output by both is the same but with the version of the variables data from the database is not loaded. But with the version where I put the values for numbers and letters, it works fine.

Does anyone know where the problem or the mistake is?

Here is a little bit detailed:

```
ob_start();
echo "{{tokens[0].token_letter}}";
$contentletter = ob_get_clean();

ob_start();
echo "{{tokens[0].token_number}}";
$contentnumber = ob_get_clean();
$conn = mysqli_connect($serverName, $userName, $password, $dbName);
if (!$conn) { die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error()); }
$sql = "SELECT name, number, letter FROM queues WHERE
number='".$contentnumber."' AND letter='".$contentletter."'";
var_dump($sql);
```

Comment: Are you getting an error when you attempt the variables one? Are you sure you are capturing errors?

Comment: I dont think its a problem with the string. Error must be somewhere else.

Comment: No i dont get any errors... it is realy curious...

Comment: You should be using prepared statements with bound parameters instead of string concatenation in the first place. Based on these two lines of code it is unlikely that anyone can tell you if you have done anything wrong.

Comment: Something's not right. That SQL string is only 73 characters long, but `var_dump()` says it's 121 bytes. Is that the real output?

Comment: string(73) "SELECT name, number, letter FROM queues WHERE number='100' AND letter='S'"

Comment: this above is the dump when i dont use the variables

Comment: string(121) "SELECT name, number, letter FROM queues WHERE number='100' AND letter='S'"

Comment: the above is the dump when i use variables